MySQL Migration from Keyring Plugin to Keyring Component [MY-011084] [Server] Keyring migration failed
For MySQL 8.0.40 on Rocky Linux, my database currently uses the keyring plugin. I want to migrate to the keyring component. It shows

[ERROR] [MY-013106] [Server] Can not perform keyring migration : Failed to initialize destination keyring.

I am working from these resources:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keyring-key-migration.html
https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/keyring-components
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108197

I see someone had success setting encryption off, but I would like to avoid that.
I created the manifest: /usr/sbin/mysqld.my.
It contains:
    {
      "components": "file://component_keyring_file"
    }

I checked that the component file exists:
ls /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_keyring_file.so #success
I created the keyring configuration file: **/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_keyring_file.cnf**. It reads:
    {
      "path": "/var/lib/mysql/mysql-keyring/component_keyring_file",
      "read_only": false
    }

I created the directory for the keyring file:
    mkdir /var/lib/mysql/mysql-keyring
    chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/mysql-keyring

After that, I stopped mysqld and tried to run the migration server. I have tried variations:
    mysqld --user=mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --keyring-migration-to-component  --keyring-migration-source=keyring_file.so  --keyring-migration-destination=component_keyring_file.so
    
    mysqld --user=mysql --keyring-migration-to-component  --keyring-migration-source=keyring_file.so  --keyring-migration-destination=component_keyring_file.so

I understand that the migrating user cannot be root, so the user is mysql. Also, the component_keyring_file cannot be in the data directory. I have tried two paths:
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-keyring # dir for mysql files

/var/lib/mysql-keyring

I updated component_keyring_file.cnf and made sure the mysql user owned the directory.

One problem is the path of the keyring file. Use this command to look up the data directory: SELECT@@datadir; . I had to use a path like /var/lib/mysql-keyring/component_keyring_file. Anything under this path will fail: /var/lib/mysql/.... I also suspect there was a permission problem. The mysql user may need to own the keyring file and have write and execute permissions on it. I suspect it may need write and execute permissions on the parent directory. I have not confirmed this.

I was not able to run the migration from the command line. It returned errors like
[MV-013106] [Server] Can not perform keyring migration : Failed to initialize destination keyring.

I performed these steps to remove the keyring_file encryption, then enable the component keyfile encryption. This answer guided me.

Disable encryption for each table using a script.
Edit /etc/my.cnf to remove the early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
directive.
Enable the component encryption:


Add the file component_keyring_file.cnf
Check ownership and write permissions on /var/lib/mysql-keyring/component_keyring_file.
Add the manifest, /usr/sbin/mysqld.my


Restart the database and check the service status.

Check the keyring component status.
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.keyring_component_status;

Enable encryption on each table using a script.


Script to generate Disable Encryption statements for a database.
SELECT
-- table_schema, table_name, table_type,
CONCAT( 'ALTER table `', table_name, '` ENCRYPTION = ''N''; ') AS alter_table
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' AND table_type ='BASE TABLE';

Script to generate Enable Encryption statements for a database.
SELECT CONCAT( 'ALTER table `', table_name, '` ENCRYPTION = ''Y''; ') AS alter_table
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' AND table_type ='BASE TABLE';

